# Changing OutlinedButton's child (Text widget) forecolor using ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using OutlinedButton widget and I want to find a specific style via themedata.
the OutlinedButton structure is like this:

```
OutlinedButton(
  child: Text("Post"),
  onPressed: () {
    context
        .read<PostsModel>()
        .addPost(_title.text, _content.text);
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => PostPage(),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

and themedata is like this:

```
MaterialApp(
    ...
    outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        ),
        side: MaterialStateProperty.all<BorderSide>(
            BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
        textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          color: Colors.white,
        )),
      ),
    ),
)
```

I was expecting to change the color like fontsize on children but it doesn't happen. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the `OutlinedButton.styleFrom` constructor, it makes things easier:

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
      ),
      primary: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
...
)
```

So for the `fontSize`, you should adjust the `TextStyle`, but if you want to change text color, `primary` is the property you should use.

Also, most probably you would need to restart the app in order for the Theme to be applied.

Comment: This solution works but I am looking for a solution using ButtonStyle.

Comment: `.styleFrom()` is just a helper method so you don’t need to use `MaterialStateProperty…` that could become cumbersome. Any specific reason why you want that?

Comment: Because `ButtonStyle`, which is used to configure the appearance of buttons like `TextButton`, `ElevatedButton`, and `OutlinedButton`, has many material state properties. The button widgets keep track of their current material state and resolve the button style's material state properties when their value is needed.